# Angular SSR build command failed

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering, angular8

I am using angular 8 and i have to do an SEO.

I use SSR for this case and followed this link for installation :
https://angular.io/guide/universal

But when i run :

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

I have these following errors:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

Any help please.

Comment: I think its related to node's testing framework error? please check this link once https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/677

Comment: Can you post the content of the scripts section of your package.json script?